# I want to group character, number and special character from String value using java?

Tags: java, string

I want to separate characters, numbers and special character from a given string input.

The goal is that the character values are grouped first and numbers are added and then print next of characters with the last special character are printed.

```
Example:
Input:sep2tr8sg0*@sdb($67)hs
Output:seotrsqsdbhs13*@($)
```

Comment: Where does the `o` in `seotr` come from? There is no `o` in the input...

Comment: Well `q` is also not there in input.. and 2 & 8 are not in the output.

Comment: the q should be a g. it kinda lines up if you squint

Comment: @Parthiban, it could have been nice if you have done better preparation before throwing a question.

Answer (score 4):

I should probably not answer but it's my pause ;-)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "sep2tr8sg0*@sdb($67)hs";

    StringBuilder letters = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder other = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) letters.append(c);
        else if (Character.isDigit(c)) numbers.append(c);
        else other.append(c);
    }

    String output = letters.append(numbers).append(other).toString();

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to separate character number and special symbol

```
 StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer(),
 num = new StringBuffer(), special = new StringBuffer();
 final String txt= txtview2.getText().toString();
 alpha1.setText(txtview2.getText().toString());
 num1.setText(txtview2.getText().toString());
 special1.setText(txtview2.getText().toString());
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"you enter string:"+txt,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 for (int i=0; i<txt.length(); i++)
 {
     if (Character.isDigit(txt.charAt(i)))
         num.append(txt.charAt(i));
     else if(Character.isLetter(txt.charAt(i)))
         alpha.append(txt.charAt(i));
     else
         special.append(txt.charAt(i);
 }
 alpha1.setText("The Character: " +alpha);
 num1.setText("The digit:" + num);
 special1.setText("The special symbol: " + special);
}
```